# Search implementation across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table like:

```
Persons  
  FirstName varchar(50)  
  LastName varchar(50)
  EmailAddress varchar(200)
```

Now, let's say I have a google like search box; in other words just one textbox with a search button.

Normally we do something like:

```
declare @searchTerm varchar(50)
set @searchTerm = 'tom'

select *
  from Persons
  where (FirstName = @searchTerm) 
     or (LastName = @searchTerm)
     or (EmailAddress = @searchTerm)
```

What I'd like to do is be able to pass both the first and last name (for example) into the @searchTerm variable, but my brain just doesn't want to build that query. ;)

For example:

```
declare @searchTerm varchar(50)
set @searchTerm = 'tom smith'

select *
  from Persons
  where ????
```

The idea is to return all records where 'tom' OR 'smith' appear in those fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really complex topic that has many subtle performance implications. You really need to read these excellent articles by Erland Sommarskog:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Since there is no "one size fits all" query approach for this, there are subtle performance implications in how you do this. If you would like to go beyond just making the query return the proper answer, no matter how slow it is, look at this article: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  It covers every method and gives PROs and Cons of each method in great detail.

If you can determine a min and a max possible range for your search column, and the search column is NOT NULL, then you can do better than the (@Search IS NULL OR Col=@Search), [see this area of the above linked article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#Umachandar).  However you should read the entire article, there are so many variations that depend on your situation, you really need to learn multiple approaches and when to use them.

if you want to search on multiple terms within a single string parameter, you need to split that string.

You need to create a split function.  This is how a split function can be used:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable                               y
    INNER JOIN dbo.yourSplitFunction(@Parameter) s ON y.ID=s.Value
```

[I prefer the number table approach to split a string in TSQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum) but there are numerous ways to split strings in SQL Server, see the previous link, which explains the PROs and CONs of each.

For the Numbers Table method to work, you need to do this one time table setup, which will create a table `Numbers` that contains rows from 1 to 10,000:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, create this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTable]
(
     @SplitOn  char(1)      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List     varchar(8000)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(

    ----------------
    --SINGLE QUERY-- --this will not return empty rows
    ----------------
    SELECT
        ListValue
        FROM (SELECT
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
                  FROM (
                           SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                       ) AS dt
                      INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
             ) dt2
        WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!=''

);
GO
```

You can now easily split a CSV string into a table and join on it:

```
select * from dbo.FN_ListToTable(',','1,2,3,,,4,5,6777,,,')
```

OUTPUT:

```
ListValue
-----------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6777

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Your can use the multiple search criteria string like this:

```
DECLARE @Persons table (FirstName varchar(50)  ,  LastName varchar(50),  EmailAddress varchar(200) )
INSERT INTO @Persons VALUES ('aaa','bbb','ccc@ddd.eee')
INSERT INTO @Persons VALUES ('xxx','yyy','zzz@abbba.zzz')
INSERT INTO @Persons VALUES ('aaa','yyy','zzz@zzz.zzz')
INSERT INTO @Persons VALUES ('111','222','333@444.555')

declare @searchTerm varchar(50)
set @searchTerm = 'aaa bbb'

--this should use an index on FirstName and LastName if they exist, no index usage on EmailAddress
select
    p.*  --<<"*" isn't good, only list the columns you need
    FROM @Persons                                      p
        INNER JOIN dbo.FN_ListToTable(' ',@searchTerm) b on p.FirstName=b.Listvalue
UNION
select
    p.*  --<<"*" isn't good, only list the columns you need
    FROM @Persons                                      p
        INNER JOIN dbo.FN_ListToTable(' ',@searchTerm) b on p.LastName=b.Listvalue
UNION
select
    p.*  --<<"*" isn't good, only list the columns you need
    FROM @Persons                                      p
        INNER JOIN dbo.FN_ListToTable(' ',@searchTerm) b on p.EmailAddress like '%'+b.Listvalue+'%'
```

OUTPUT:

```
FirstName  LastName   EmailAddress
---------- ---------- -------------------------
aaa        bbb        ccc@ddd.eee
aaa        yyy        zzz@zzz.zzz
xxx        yyy        zzz@abbba.zzz

(3 row(s) affected)
```

this method will work for any number of parameters:

```
aaa
 aaa
aaa bbb
aaa  bbb
aaa bbb eee
aaa bbb eee ddd
aaa   bbb   eee
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
DECLARE
    @searchTerm VARCHAR(100),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    @LastName VARCHAR(100)
SET
    @searchTerm = 'tom smith'

SELECT
    @FirstName = '%' + SUBSTRING(@searchTerm, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @searchTerm) - 1) + '%',
    @LastName = '%' + SUBSTRING(@searchTerm, CHARINDEX(' ', @searchTerm) + 1, LEN(@searchTerm)) + '%'

SELECT *
FROM
    Persons
WHERE
    FirstName LIKE @FirstName
OR  LastName LIKE @FirstName
OR  EmailAddress LIKE @FirstName
OR  FirstName LIKE @LastName
OR  LastName LIKE @LastName
OR  EmailAddress LIKE @LastName
```